# Странное поведение getBoundingRect() в Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css

Встретился сегодня с одной странностью (не исключаю собственную криворукость) при использовании getBoundingClientRect. Суть такова: есть код (упрощен для облегчения чтения, однако на результате это никак не сказалось)

```js
let c = document.querySelector('#container');
let b = c.getBoundingClientRect();
console.log(b, c);
```

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;;
}

.container {
 background: aqua;
 height: 400px;
 width: 600px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 
}
.circle {
 background: tomato;
 border-radius: 50%;
 cursor: pointer;
 height: 25px;
 left: 0;
 text-align: center;
 top: 0;
 width: 25px;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="container" id="container">
  <div class="circle"></div>
 </div>
</body>
```

При локальном запуске в Firefox координаты сперва показываются верно, но стоит изменить размеры окна, как они тут же сбрасываются и перестают иметь хоть какое-то отношение к элементу.
При запуске в Firefox при помощи Live Server (расширение в Visual Studio Code) все работает нормально при любых манипуляциях.
При проверке в CodePen и JSBin все работало также хорошо. В Chrome, что при локальном запуске, что через Live Server, координаты выводились верно.

Вот мне и стало интересно, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Возможно, проблема в том, что размеры элемента посчитались 1 раз и все? После каких-либо манипулаций их надо пересчитать заново

Comment: @Дмытрык была такая мысль, но тогда почему все работает с Live Server (о внутреннем устройстве данной дополения не осведомлен, поэтому могу что-то упускать) или в Chrome, который у меня настроен практически также, как и Firefox?

Comment: live server же обновляет окно ?

Comment: @MaximLensky Да, обновляет. Но чем это обновление отличается от ручного?

Comment: Добавьте код, который будет воспроизводить проблему. Приведенный код, у меня, в Chrome, ведет ожидаемо - 1 раз, при запуске, посчитал и все

Comment: @Дмытрык В Chrome у меня проблем нет. И в Firefox при первом запуске все выводит верно.

Comment: а проблема тогда в чем?

Comment: @Дмытрык Запускаю в Firefox, все просчитывает, изменяю размер окна, обновляю страницу - новые координаты никак не относятся к элементу, к которому должны.

Comment: не может такого быть. Как проверку делаете?

Comment: @Дмытрык Через консоль, если вы про это.

Comment: я про то, как Вы соотносите, что данные выведенные в консоль никак не соответствуют элементу, на экране?

Comment: @Дмытрык Первый запуск, вывод в консоли: bottom: 400 height: 400 left: 383 right: 983 top: 0 width: 600 x: 383 y: 0
Открытие справа консоли, обновление страницы, вывод: bottom: 8 height: 0 left: 8 right: 868 top: 8 width: 860 x: 8 y: 8

Comment: переместите подключаемый скрипт в конец body. Повторите попытку

Comment: @Дмытрык Так все работает, спасибо. Но почему так?

Comment: Потому что на момент выполнения скрипта элемента еще не было  в DOM

Comment: @Дмытрык Но ведь у меня скрипт был с defer.

Comment: @Дмытрык А как именно обновлять? Сражаюсь с .getBoundingClientRect() :)